How to count the number of memory allocations Perl has made during a sub-routine call
I have a very non-performant sub-routine, I believe it's not performant because it's doing way too many allocations. Before I commit to fixing it, I'd like to learn how to count the number of allocations that happen during this sub-routine from within the Perl code itself. Ideally this will be a performant operation, such that I can implement an observation system atop the rest of the code to track down other greedy slow pokes.
Is there any way for me to use Perl to introspect how many allocations Perl has made at a given time? Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:
sub get_number_of_allocs_from_sub {
    my ($sub, @args) = @_;
    # magic
    $sub->(@args);
    # more magic
    return $num_allocs;
}

In Ruby I would use something like allocation_stats or ObjectSpace.

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips#PERL_MEM_LOG ?

This is a really really weird hyopthesis. Start with a profiler (e.g. NYTProf)

@ikegami The sub does a lot of blocking stuff so I would expect the performance to be related to those (Database operations, etc), but I've observed memory being far greater than I would expect, which lead me down this road. Plus, I think this would be a useful skill to have in my belt.

So ignore those when you analyze

NYTProf is (one of) the way(s) to go.

@smonff Can I profile the sub at runtime though? I've never used NYTProf outside of profiling entire applications.
